# Problem installing latest faience theme on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, themes, faenza

I followed these articles to install the latest version of faience theme on ubuntu 14.04

http://www.webupd8.org/2014/06/popular-faience-gtk-gnome-shell-themes.html
http://www.noobslab.com/2014/06/faience-theme-is-now-available-for.html

And I'm getting the following error:

```
Preparing to unpack .../faience-theme_0.7_all.deb ...
Unpacking faience-theme (0.7) over (0.5.4) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/faience-theme_0.7_all.deb (--unpack):
 unable to open '/usr/share/themes/Faience-Ocre/gtk-2.0/apps/dummy.png.dpkg-new': No such file or directory
No apport report written because the error message indicates an issue on the local system
     Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/faience-theme_0.7_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

that dummy.png.dpkg-new seems a bit suspicious...

Is anybody else having the same trouble?

Comment: Whenever I run into an issue like that with dpkg, I try to purge everything to do with the package I'm running (using apt-get) and then try it again. In this case, you're better off using the PPA; I'm on an almost-naked fresh install of 14.04 and it works great here.

Comment: does the faience-ocre-dark theme works ok for you?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the package maintainer has released the fix the next day as version 0.7.1. See the changes here: https://launchpadlibrarian.net/177159549/faience-theme_0.7.1_source.changes.

Also make sure you are using `ppa:tiheum/equinox` instead of `ppa:noobslab/themes`. The package has not been updated to the lastest in the latter ppa until now.